# driver.hideKeyboard(); is not available on iOS but I am able to use it on Android and its working fine

Tags: node.js, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

> it's working fine on Android

```
submitEmail(email) {
this.emailInPutField.click();
this.emailInPutField.setValue(email);
driver.hideKeyboard();
this.confirmButton.click();
```

}

> But when I want to use the same for iOS its cant give option for driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
IOSDriver< WebElement> AD= (IOSDriver) driver;
AD.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

**Note: it will not work if you are inside multi-line input field**

Comment: driver function itself is not appearing. when I write driver it replaces with webdriver.
but on Android it's working perfectly fine. I did not understand why.

Comment: How you are accessing driver instance?

Comment: I want to use this `driver.hideKeyboard();` But when I write driver nothing appears.

Comment: Please try the solution i have mentioned

Comment: **Error** ReferenceError: Keys is not defined